# Creating NativeScript app with Teleriks AppBuilder

Tags: telerik-appbuilder, nativescript

I am writing hello world on nativeScript at AppBuilder platform. I created new project from template. It works perfetct with companion app (Run->Build->NativeScript) but i can't:
1) run it on iOS or android emulator
2) build app package  (Run->Build->App Package)

Thanks much

Comment: Which AppBuilder client are you using? You can deploy to an Android emulator from the Windows client, Visual Studio extension, and CLI. You can deploy to the iOS simulator using the CLI on a Mac. You should be able to build an app package from any of the clients on any OS.

Comment: Sorry, I am using it from browser

Answer (score 3):

From the browser you can't run on native emulators, but you can deploy to the NativeScript companion app for Android/iOS, and you can also build app packages for Android/iOS.

To build iOS app packages you need to register for the iOS developer program and [register your provisioning profiles and certificates with AppBuilder](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps) before you can create app packages. If you have any other questions related to this let me know.